# Proving two elements of a group are equal.

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to do the following question:

$e_1$ and $e_2$ are elements of group such that for all g in G, $$e_1g = ge_1 = g$$ and $$e_2g = ge_2 = g$$ How can we prove that $e_1 = e_2$?

Clearly, they are both identities of the group G, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you first expression, take $g = e_2$, that means

$$
e_1 e_2 = e_2 \tag{1}
$$

in your second expression take $g = e_1$

$$
e_2 e_1 = e_1e_2 = e_1 \tag{2}
$$

Putting together (1) and (2):

$$
e_1 = e_2
$$